# Github and Tauri keys

Tags: reactjs, github, gitlab-ci, tauri

Dear Stackoverflow friends!

**We want to publish and show releases in the main github repo of our application:** https://github.com/codefen/codefend-user

[image]

But we have sensitive Tauri content, which we don't know how sensitive / good practice it would be. Is there any way we can sort this out and create releases for fast download.?

We don't know how to proceed here, as this is the first time we face this situation...

Comment: What kind of sensitive content? Secrets in source code?

Comment: Hi Benjamin! Thanks for supporting, it's actually Tauri related keys, as far as I understand, I'll gather more information shortly.